# Combining two correct answers

Tags: discussion, support, answers, accepted-answer

I have [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291087/how-to-solve-an-equation-with-x4) question which asks for both the real and non-real solutions of an equation and the methods I could use for them. Problem is however, there is one correct answer on the real part, and there is one correct one on the imaginary part (which was asked in the question). What should I do? I feel like creating an answer myself, based on the two answers, is "hijacking" rep from the original answers and accepting multiple answers is not possible as far as I know...

Comment: One way to go: Upvote both answers, make a *community wiki* answer by yourself that merge the answers (and cite the other answers that you based your answer on).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the end of the day the decision is mainly up to you.

Here are some of my own personal thoughts:

- Upvote any answer that has been helpful to you. Maybe they don't fully answer your question, but if they are helpful, upvote them.
- If you don't feel that any answer has satisfactorily solved your problem, don't accept any answer.
- You are free to post an answer combining the main parts of the half-solutions to create an answer that fully solves your problem. You should [properly reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) any parts which are not originally yours.  Additionally, any direct quotes should be placed in

  > blockquotes.

  (It should go without saying that such an answer should not consist solely of quotes and references. You should add *something* to the mix.)

  *I* don't think it is necessary to make your answer community wiki, though that is an option and [consolidating the knowledge of the community](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) is one of the main intended uses for CW.

  Note that even if you accept a self-answer like this, you're not really "hijacking" reputation. Accepted self-answers yield neither the 15 reputation points from having an answer accepted, nor the 2 reputation points from accepting an answer. (So if you weren't going to accept any answer because none fully solved your problem, no-one has really lost or gained reputation by the *acceptance* of a self-answer.) Maybe you earn reputation by others upvoting the complete solution, but putting everything in one place is certainly an action that can arguably be seen as deserving of reputation. (Fair warning: you might also earn downvotes if people feel that the self-answer was in bad faith.)

Comment: "I don't think it is necessary to make your answer community wiki" makes fully sense to me if the answer is **not exclusively** composed of "parts which are not originally yours".